# Missing Other Project Types in visual studio 2012

Tags: vb.net

I want to create my installer. But missing Other Project Type > Visual Studio Installer > Setup Project

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not supported anymore on VS2012.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

VDProjects are no longer supported. Either:

1. Use older versions of visual studio to build existing VDPROJ project types (you can keep them in the solution)
2. If creating new installers, use a framework such as WiX which contains Visual Studio integration. Little bit of a learning curve, but a very good product (and free). This will produce an MSI from XML within a WiX project in visual studio after you install it.

http://wixtoolset.org/